# Sample program for RaspiCam API not compiling

Tags: camera, raspicam, c++

I have been trying to compile the sample RaspiCam program provided on their [project page](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40).
When I try to compile the code using the following:

```
g++ simpletest_raspicam.cpp -o simpletest_raspicam -L/opt/vc/lib -I/usr/local/include -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util
```

I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccLyTfLB.o: In function `main':
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::RaspiCam()'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::open(bool)'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::grab()'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::getImageTypeSize(raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT) const'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::retrieve(unsigned char*, raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT)'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::getWidth() const'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::getHeight() const'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::getImageTypeSize(raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT) const'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::~RaspiCam()'
simpletest_raspicam.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam::~RaspiCam()'
```

Does anyone have the same problem? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're supposed to download `raspicam` library source to your raspi and compile it using:

```
tar xvzf raspicamxx.tgz
cd raspicamxx
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..

make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

before you'll be able to compile other programs.

Comment: I have downloaded the `raspicam-0.1.1.zip` file from the [http://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/] SourceForge. Installed it using the commands you mentioned. Instead I used `cd raspicam-0.1.1` for second line.

Comment: i would try to download `raspicam-0.0.5.tgz (71.3 kB)` first, then proceed to the latest version.

Comment: It worked... just had to install .5, .7, and 1.1 in that order for it to work

Comment: @lenik Do you have to install 2 versions 1 after another?  SO you run the series of command you specified twice once with 0.0.5 and once with latest?  COuld you elaborate on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem ist: Cmake dont made the raspicam_still lib, only the raspicam lib. 
An if you dont work every day with cmake, you cannot configure it, cmake is crazy.

At this time you cannot use raspicam still for photos, only raspycam for Video.